# Why coroutine is not working properly in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Sometimes when I step on a red box the timer doens't stop and the buff is always on. Why is this happening? I think this is something related with the couroutines, but I can't figure why. Here is the main code:

```
       private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
        {
            if (coll.transform.CompareTag("Player") && !_isFalling)
            {
                StartCoroutine(HexFalling());
                if (type == HexGrid.TypeHex.good)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(coll.gameObject.GetComponent<ThirdPersonMovement>().BuffSpeed(3f, 0.5f));
                }

                else if (type == HexGrid.TypeHex.bad)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(coll.gameObject.GetComponent<ThirdPersonMovement>().BuffSpeed(0.5f, 1.5f));
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the code for one coroutine:

```
        private IEnumerator HexFalling()
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material = _matIsFalling;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_timeToFall);
            _isFalling = true;
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deactivating the object that is used for running your coroutine. It is interrupting the coroutine execution.

Also, your coroutine `HexFalling()` can be called multiple times because `_isFalling` is not set to `true` immediately. It will be set to `true` only in `_timeToFall` seconds after the collision.